# How do I create a custom file format on Windows, with the interpreter being in, say, JavaScript, or Python?

Tags: python

I would like to try to interpret it like a .json file for some user generated content for my game. I'm not a perfect coder, so yeah. I've tried looking it up online, and on MS Docs, but the Docs are about stuff like C++. I have a .py file, and I've used open() to open it. But how can I export it into an object?

Comment: You write _I would like to try to interpret like a .json file, not exactly like interchange, but like a data storage file, like user generated content for my game_, but then say _So let's say I have a .py file. How do I let Python read it?_ shortly after. I'm a bit confused, are you looking to create your own data storage format, or programming language, or something else entirely?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to be more specific - what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention "like a .json file", so if you chose to store your content in valid JSON format, you could [read the file into Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and then [parse the JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to get the data into Python objects.

Otherwise, file extensions are all convention anyway, so you could create a file with whatever contents you want, call it `gamefiles.datastore`, and then read it into Python and parse it with a parser (that you would have to write for your custom data storage solution).

Comment: How do I store it like in json format without .json? (See the stuff I added on main post)